# Gnuplot - plot connected points from bash script

Tags: bash, awk, gnuplot

in my script I am trying to print two sets of points - one of them will be somewhere around the middle and the other will be on top of the gnuplot terminal. I am using this for cycle twice to do it :

```
for ((i=1;i<=LINES;i++))
do
    {
        cat <<-PLOT
            set terminal png
            set output "$(printf "$FMT" $i)"
            plot [0:$LINES][$YRANGE1:$YRANGE2] '-' with lines t ''
            PLOT
        head -n $i "${TMPDIR}/bigdata"
    } | gnuplot
done
```

But when I do it like this the points simply continue behind the YRANGE2 - I want them to start from the beginning again. How do I do that ? The file looks like this :

```
100.285
100.404
100.708
100.199
....
130.628
130.865
130.186
130.659
```

Also I have tried to append the line numbers in awk, but then I couldn't print it with the for cycle I have poster earlier - I have tried appendeding `using 2:1` but it just didn't work. Any hints please ?

Thank you very much

Comment: It's probably very clear to you what you want but unless you post your desired output we wouldn't know.

Comment: Is the problem that you can't figure out how to generate the data you want or that you are generating what you think you need but gnuplot is not interpreting it as you expect? If the former, take gnuplot out of the equation and just post your sample input/output where the output would be the input to gnuplot. If the latter then post the input you are providing to gnuplot so someone can help you with that.

Comment: btw you should really read http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice so you can get away from all this shell loop nonsense.

Answer (score -1):

thanks everybody for their comments, the solution was to indeed use awk to add second column and then edit the for cycle like this :

```
for ((i=1;i<=LINES;i++))
do
    {
        cat <<-PLOT
            set terminal png
            set output "$(printf "$FMT" $i)"
            set xrange [0:$LINES]
            set yrange [$YRANGE1:$YRANGE2]
            plot '-' using 2:1 with lines t ''
            PLOT
        head -n $i "${TMPDIR}/bigdata"
    } | gnuplot
done
```